# How to control edit access to Role?

Tags: administration, security, data, role-hierarchy

I have a role Sales Manager. The sub roles of Sales Manager are Sales Rep A and Sales Rep B.
The records created by Sales Rep A user and B user are seen by Sales Manager. It is done by Role level Hierarchy. The Sales Manager can able to view and Edit the Sales Rep records. How can I give permission to Sales Manager only view and not edit access to sales reps records.

Things I have done : The Org wide default for the Object is Private . Checked the Grant Access Using Hierarchies checkbox. Though the Sales Manager is able to edit the sub role records.
Where I am going wrong? Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1. Go to sharing settings > edit > Disable option "Grant Access using hierarchies
Step 2. can Assign same permission set as Sales rep A and B

Answer (score 0):

The role hierarchy automatically grants record access to users above the record owner in the hierarchy.

As you mentioned the Sales Rep A  and Sales Rep B are under Sales Manager role and you have enabled Grant Access Using Hierarchies checkbox . As in the hierarchy  Sales Manager is higher so it gets all the access of the records of lower roles and the functionality is working as expected.

Please find the below [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000326216&type=1) for the same

If you dont want the access to the higher roles you may need to uncheck the Grant Access Using Hierarchies checkbox.